# I can't remove mysql as I cannot stop it

Tags: apt, mysql, uninstall, debian, configuration-management

I want to remove mysql-server but I cannot do so until I stop the service. However, when first downloading it, it didn't start to begin with. So now if I try and start or stop it I get the error message "Unit mysql.service not found." and "Unit mysql.service not loaded." respectively.

So I tried manually deleting it by removing /etc/mysql and /var/lib/mysql but by doing that I can no longer reload it to maybe salvage the situation.

To be clear, I need to stop it before I can remove it, but to stop it, it has to be started to begin with, and to start it it must be loaded, and since I deleted it's conf files it cannot be reloaded... What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to solve it in a round about way. Running the following command:

*systemctl list-unit-files --type service -all | grep mysql*

will print all the services currently on your computer. service.mysql had a status of "bad" for me which caused the problem, so I ran the command:

*sudo systemctl disable mysql.service*

to disable it. Having done that I then stopped it by:

*sudo systemctl stop mysql.service*

and finally I deleted everything relating to sql by:

*sudo apt remove --purge mysql-**